# Type hint for inheritance from parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, python-typing

I am trying to get proper auto-completion for a decorated class. The Problem is that the decorator doesn't just change the class but it creates and returns a new one, derived from the decorated class and another class.
In other words, I need to annotate a functions return value as the parameter **and** a base class.
Here a simplified example:

```py
class A:
    def func_a(self): pass

def decorator(cls): # what type hint comes here?
    class Result(cls, A):
        pass
    return Result

@decorator
class B:
    def func_b(self): pass

obj = B()
obj.func_a()
obj.func_b()
```

Here my IDE detects func_a but not func_b.

In TypeScript the solution would be something like

```js
decorator<T>(cls: T): A & T
```

It seems python doesn't have this & operator for type hints. Which annotation do I use? Or is it just not possible?